# How can I use a URL's search engine to return the result of the search?

Tags: java, search-engine

I've read some tutorials, and I understand what's going on here:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html

My question is, how can I use a URL or URLConnection to access the result of a search.
For instance, if my URL was:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.stackoverflow.com/");
```

how could I access the search-engine at the top of the page to return the results of a search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the page source. It will contain a `<form>` element. Its `action` property will hold the URL of the search script. You also have to send your keywords using the name defined in the `<input>` tag inside the form.

Using SO as the example:

```
                <form id="search" action="/search" method="get">

                <div>

                    <input name="q" class="textbox" tabindex="1" onfocus="if (this.value=='search') this.value = ''" type="text" maxlength="140" size="28" value="search">

                </div>

                </form>
```

Will give the following URL:

```
http://www.stackoverflow.com/search?q=your+keywords+here
```

You have to encode your search terms using URL encoding. The very basic thing here is to substitute spaces with the character `+`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried using string concatenation to combine the search URL along with the encoded string, but I'm having an issue. I keep getting the error: "java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol:" It seems that the form redirects to the correct page if there's a perfect match. Could this be causing the error?

Comment: Yes: the form uses a **relative URL**. As you can see from the example: relative URL's have to be solved. Ifthe URL starts with the character `/` then the origin is the root of the web folder, so you have to reepend the protocol and domain name. In the example `/search` becomes `http://www.stackoverflow.com/search` because that's the way to handle relative URL's starting with the slash character. It is also possible that the url would look like `search`. Please consult this document about solving URL's in HTML pages: http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970917/htmlweb.html